# Как добавить шаблон single.php для произвольного типа записи в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

У меня несколько типов постов, реализовано как произвольные записи, подскажите как сделать для них отдельный шаблон?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто. single-имя_вашей_произвольной_записи